# How to get the size of the visible part of a view on screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

Say I have a view, part of it is shown on the screen, and part of it is out of screen. I would like to the get the size of the visible part.

Comment: With the coordinates of the view in the main view of your controller ? You know everything : sizes and origins

Comment: for the width : 
theWidthOfView - theXofTheView 
or for the height : 
theHeightOfView - theYofTheView